# Javascript Validate form group field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form where I can add dynamically new section with fields. How can I chceck that this dynamically input is valid (not empty).

My code:

```
var i= 0;
$("#addSection").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        i++;

 var html = '<div>';
    html += '<input type="text" name="person['+ i +'][name]" value="" />';
    html +='<input type="text" name="person['+ i '][surname]" value="" /></div>';
var section= $(html);
    $('#myDiv').append(section);

    });
```

This create like:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="person[1][name]" value="" />
   <input type="text" name="person[1][surname]" value="" />
  </div>
<div>
   <input type="text" name="person[2][name]" value="" />
   <input type="text" name="person[2][surname]" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to validate only names person[1][name], person[2][name], person[3][name], etc. How can I validate this fields when I click submit button?

Comment: the word "valid" is subjective. what do you mean? is it valid if contains at least 3 vowels? are only female names valid? only names of muppets? what are you talking about. be more specific.

Comment: oh.., you mean not empty.. however you're using the name attribute wrong. that should be static. it's an identifier, it's not meant to store a value.

Comment: anyway `if(theName.trim==="") //it's not valid` replace theName with the value from the input. good luck getting the value from the input when you're using the name attribute like that though.